# Ajax does not store the data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a program which I am able to add datas without javascript. But I would like to use AJAX and I do not know why it does not work. When I click Add button it does happen nothing and I do not see the data in phpmyadmin. Can anyone help me?

index.php:

```
session_start();
require_once("auth.php");
require_once("control.php"); 

<div class="well well-sm bs-component">
    <div class="form-group row add">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <div class="col-md-12">
         <label for="content" class="control-label">Your Comment</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<?= $id; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?= date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ?>">
            <textarea  id="content" name="content" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Enter your comment..." required></textarea>
            <p class="error text-center alert alert-danger hidden"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="addButton col-md-12">
            <button class="btn" type="submit" id="add" name="add">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> SEND
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>      
</div>
```

control.php:

```
//ADD COMMENT
if ( isset($_POST['add']) ) {
$id = $_POST['uid'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$content = $_POST['content'];

$sql= "INSERT INTO posts (uid, content, date) VALUES ('$id', '$content', '$date')";

if (!$mysqli->query($sql)) {
 header("location: error.php");
}
}
```

Javascript:

```
$("#add").click(function() {

var formData = {
    'name': $('#content').val()
    };


    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'control.php',
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
            if ((data.errors)){
                $('.error').removeClass('hidden');
                $('.error').text(data.errors.name);
            }
            else { 
                $('.error').addClass('hidden');
                $('#table').prepend("<div class='item" + data.id + " mess'><div class='btn-group-sm'><button class='edit-modal btn btn-circle' data-id=" + data.id + " data-name=" + data.name +"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></button><button class='delete-modal btn btn-circle' data-id=" + data.id + " data-name=" + data.name +"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></button></div><article class='myMessage'><p>" + data.name + "</p></article></div><div class='clear' style='clear: both;''></div>");
            }
        },

    });
    $('#content').val('');

});
```

Comment: what you should do to isolate the error if you're not sure is to add some debug messages to your code to actually see where your date is "lost" or how far it gets. E.g. add an `echo`message to your `control.php` and see if it is even called and if so check the correct values

Comment: You aren't sending `$_POST['add']`. Output in the PHP so you know where your application stops. Also you should use error reporting on the query so you know why it failed and should parameterize the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending only this as the `$_POST` data:

```
var formData = {
    'name': $('#content').val()
};
```

Which should result only to `$_POST['name']` => VALUE

But you are reading from `$_POST['content'];` and other vars.
You also check for `$_POST['add']` which is not being sent by your AJAX.
Change the key, you are using to send/read the data on one side and also try to add the other keys/values to your data, e.g.

```
var formData = {
    'add': 'yes',
    'content': $('#content').val(),
    'uid': SOMEVALUE,
    'date': SOMEVALUE
};
```

The `uid` and the `date` are things you might wanna create in your control.php dynamically anyway. But then don't read them from `$_POST`

ADDITION: Further reading with an example that matches your use case: https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
you are just passing name. you have to pass uid and date also
var formData = {
    'name': $('#content').val()
    };

with this.
give id to uid and date textfield
var formData = {
    'name': $('#content').val(),
    'uid': $('#uid').val(),
    'date': $('#date').val(),
    };


in control.php database connection is necessary. without it record will not inserted
```